# wait(status), WEXITSTATUS(status) always returns 0

Tags: c, unix

I'm working on a c program that uses fork() exec() wait().
The first process has this code:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
// insert code here...

int pid = fork();

if(pid == 0){
    //we are the child process.
    execlp("/Users/matthewdunn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PA2-hekivoaqvsegnggdvcfguasystig/Build/Products/Debug/Checker", "Checker", "1", "5", (char*) NULL);
}else{
    //we are the parent process.
    printf("Coordinator: forked process with ID ");
    printf("%d\n", pid);

    printf("Coordinator: waiting for process [");
    printf("%d", pid);
    printf("]\n");

    int status;
    waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
    int returned = WEXITSTATUS(status);

    printf("Coordinator: child process ");
    printf("%d", pid);
    printf(" returned ");
    printf("%d", returned);
    printf(".\n");
}



  return 0;
}
```

The second process has the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void printProcessInfo(){
    printf("Checker process [");
    printf("%d", getpid());
    printf("]:  ");
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...

    printProcessInfo();
    printf("Starting.\n");

    int arg1;
    int arg2;

    arg1 = atoi(argv[1]);
    arg2 = atoi(argv[2]);

    if((arg2 % arg1) > 0){
        printProcessInfo();
        printf("%d", arg2);
        printf(" *IS NOT* divisible by ");
        printf("%d\n", arg1);

        printProcessInfo();
        printf("Returning 0.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        printProcessInfo();
        printf("%d", arg2);
        printf(" *IS* divisible by ");
        printf("%d\n", arg1);

        printProcessInfo();
        printf("Returning 1.\n");
        return 1;
    }

}
```

For a reason that I cannot figure out, the parent function always reads a return value of 0, even though I get the falling output:

```
Coordinator: forked process with ID 2865 
Coordinator: waiting for process [2865] 
Checker process [2865]:  Starting. 
Checker process [2865]:  5 *IS* divisible by 1 
Checker process [2865]:  Returning 1.
Coordinator: child process 2865 returned 0. 
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

The second process is clearly returning 1, yet I'm still getting a 0 for the status. I have no idea what could be causing this. I'm writing this code using Xcode. Is there a reason why WEXITSTATUS(status) always returns 0?

Comment: It still always returns 0 after fixing the pointer issue.

Comment: Can't see any obvious problems. I tried your code and it worked as expected for me (parent say child return 1).

Comment: Note that your code may report zero if the child exited with a signal (SIGSEGV or whatever).  That shouldn't be the problem, but in theory you should be using `WIFEXITED(status)` before using `WEXITSTATUS()`, and you can use `WIFSIGNALED(status)` to determine if it was signalled and then `WTERMSIG(status)` to get the signal number, and `WCOREDUMP(status)` to check if there was a core dump, and `WIFSTOPPED(status)` to check if the process was stopped.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here:

```
int* status;
waitpid(pid, status, 0);
```

your pointer `status` is never set to actually point to anything. You need an actual `int` to store the value:

```
int status;
waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
```

If you're specifically interested in the exit status, you should also be checking to make sure it actually exited normally. Suffice to say, like all system calls, you should be checking the return from `waitpid()` for errors before attempting to do anything with that value.

Altogether:

```
int status;
if ( waitpid(pid, &status, 0) != -1 ) {
    if ( WIFEXITED(status) ) {
        int returned = WEXITSTATUS(status);
        printf("Exited normally with status %d\n", returned);
    }
    else if ( WIFSIGNALED(status) ) {
        int signum = WTERMSIG(status);
        printf("Exited due to receiving signal %d\n", signum);
    }
    else if ( WIFSTOPPED(status) ) {
        int signum = WSTOPSIG(status);
        printf("Stopped due to receiving signal %d\n", signum);
    }
    else {
        printf("Something strange just happened.\n");
    }
}
else {
    perror("waitpid() failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Here's a working example:

`parent.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(void)
{
    int pid = fork();

    if ( pid == -1 ) {
        perror("fork() failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else if ( pid == 0 ) {
        execlp("./child", "child", "1", "5", (char *)NULL);
        perror("execlp() failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else {
        printf("Coordinator: forked and waiting for process %d\n", pid);

        int status;
        if ( waitpid(pid, &status, 0) != -1 ) {
            if ( WIFEXITED(status) ) {
                int returned = WEXITSTATUS(status);
                printf("Exited normally with status %d\n", returned);
            }
            else if ( WIFSIGNALED(status) ) {
                int signum = WTERMSIG(status);
                printf("Exited due to receiving signal %d\n", signum);
            }
            else if ( WIFSTOPPED(status) ) {
                int signum = WSTOPSIG(status);
                printf("Stopped due to receiving signal %d\n", signum);
            }
            else {
                printf("Something strange just happened.\n");
            }
        }
        else {
            perror("waitpid() failed");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`child.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void printProcessInfo()
{
    printf("Checker process [%d]: ", getpid());
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    printProcessInfo();
    printf("Starting.\n");

    int arg1, arg2;

    arg1 = atoi(argv[1]);
    arg2 = atoi(argv[2]);

    if ( (arg1 != 0) && (arg2 % arg1) > 0 ){
        printProcessInfo();
        printf("%d *IS NOT* divisible by %d\n", arg2, arg1);
        printProcessInfo();
        printf("Returning 0.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        printProcessInfo();
        printf("%d *IS* divisible by %d\n", arg2, arg1);
        printProcessInfo();
        printf("Returning 1.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

with output:

```
paul@horus:~/src/sandbox/ft$ ./parent
Coordinator: forked and waiting for process 40330
Checker process [40330]: Starting.
Checker process [40330]: 5 *IS* divisible by 1
Checker process [40330]: Returning 1.
Exited normally with status 1
paul@horus:~/src/sandbox/ft$
```

EDIT: If you're building this in Xcode, what's happening is your `waitpid()` call is getting interrupted by a signal (most probably `SIGCHLD`). In this case, you just need to restart it, like so:

```
int status;
while ( waitpid(pid, &status, 0) == -1 ) {
    if (errno == EINTR) {
        printf("Parent interrrupted - restarting...\n");                   
        continue;
    }
    else {
        perror("waitpid() failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

if ( WIFEXITED(status) ) {
    int returned = WEXITSTATUS(status);
    printf("Exited normally with status %d\n", returned);
}
else if ( WIFSIGNALED(status) ) {
    int signum = WTERMSIG(status);
    printf("Exited due to receiving signal %d\n", signum);
}
else if ( WIFSTOPPED(status) ) {
    int signum = WSTOPSIG(status);
    printf("Stopped due to receiving signal %d\n", signum);
}
else {
    printf("Something strange just happened.\n");
}
```

Comment: And it's a good idea to check (if not save) the return value because if it is `-1`, then there isn't anything useful stored in `status` (there wasn't a child to report on).

Comment: Still returns 0. I was using int status and &status a while, at some point I just changed it to int* out of desperation and forgot to change it back.

Comment: Okay, so using that code, I've determined that the process isn't exiting. Any ideas as to why it's not exiting? Shouldn't returning the value in main exit the process?

Comment: @Matthias: If your code is exactly as you have posted it, and you are seeing `Returning 1` being output, then it is definitely exiting normally. Nevertheless, try the amended code, and if still no joy, post the *exact* code you're running.

Comment: @Matthias: Also, since you're using an IDE and making this kind of exercise difficult for yourself thereby, double check to make sure you're not doing something silly like pointing `execlp()` at an old version of your program that prints `Returning 1` but then actually returns `0`.

Comment: I copied and pasted the exact same code that you posted, but I'm getting the "waitpid() failed" message. It must be something subtle with Xcode. I'll try using a different compiler.

Comment: @Matthias: Yes, Xcode is causing `waitpid()` to be interrupted, and you'll need to restart it. See update to answer.

Comment: Well done — the new code is pretty close to what I'd just assembled. The only major difference from what you show was the ability to choose the arguments for the checker program by passing them to the runner program and having it pass those if provided and the defaults if not.  I also printed the 'corpse' (PID) returned by `waitpid()` and the status value in hex.  When I use `runner aleph null`, I got signal 8 (SIGFPE) from the checker for the (integer) divide by zero.  I also added error reporting in case the checker failed to execute; that wasn't the OPs problem though since the program ran.